# Database design for food ordering system (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need some help designing the database of a food ordering system.

**Customer**
Customer_id (PK)
Customer_name
Customer_phonenum
Payment_method (Cash/Credit Card)
Payment_status (Paid/Unpaid)
Email_address
Employee_id (FK)
OrderF_id (FK)
OrderD_id (FK)

**Employee**
Employee_id (PK)
Employee_name
Employee_position
Employee_age
Employee_phonenum
password

**Food**
Food_id (PK)
Food_name
Food_size
Food_price (Describe price of each food)

**Drinks**
Drink_id (PK)
Drink_name
Drink_size
Drink_category (which explains hot/cold)
Drink_price (Describe price of each drink)

**OrderFood**
OrderF_id (PK)
Customer_id (FK)
Employee_id (FK)
Food_id (FK)
Quantity_item
Total_price

**OrderDrinks**
OrderD_id (PK)
Employee_id (FK)
Drink_id (FK)
Quantity_item
Total_Price

1. How should I make it in such a way that a customer can order a different type of food with a different quantity in the OrderFood and OrderDrinks tables?
2. Should I repeat the Food_price and Drink_price in OrderFood and OrderDrinks respectively?
3. For employee password, how should I limit the length between 6-15 characters? (I thought of using varchar, but it also allows 1 char to be the employee's password.)

Comment: A good SQL tutorial will help you. You need to mention whether you are using SQL Server or MySQL. Also You need to post what you have tried. What you have asked may also be found on the internet. This forum addresses the problems that a developer comes across and is not a place to get tutorials. I suggest you modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Abhishek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1)
Fisrt, remove the foreign keys from the customer table, and the purchase fields.  Then create an orders table similar to this

```
Orders
    id
    CustomerId (FK)
    EmployeeId (FK)
    PurchaseMethod
    PurchaseStatus
    TimeStamp
    TotalPrice
```

Then you would create an association table that links your order to the food and drink items.  With this table, you can link as many food items to an order as needed.

```
FoodOrders
    id
    OrderId (FK)
    FoodId (FK)
    Quantity
    TotalPrice
```

Create a similar table for your drink orders.

The totals columns would have to be calculated when an order is placed.

2)
Only repeat the price data if it is necessary for your business process.  Best methods are to not repeat data if avoidable

3)
Depends on database used, SQL server has CHECK constraint you can use with the Len() to limit minimum size

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How should I make it in such a way that a customer can order different type of food with different quantity in the orderfood and orderdrink table?

Make the PK compound fields such that each record in those order tables become unique. Then you can add multiple records for food and drink for the same customer/customer ID. But your current schema is incomplete. For example, there is no customer_ID in OrderDrinks.

> 2. Should I repeat the food_price and drink_price in orderfood and orderdrink respectively?

No.

> 3. For employee password, how should I limit the length between 6-15 characters?

By using the appropriate authentication mechanism of the SQL server system. You did not mention which SQL you are using. If you want to manage this yourself, you should know the pitfalls. Any good SQL book can give you a good outline.